# Error with @EnableAutoConfiguration and @@ComponentScan using Spring Boot + Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, spring-boot

I'm using the example Spring-Boot and Spring-Data for an exercise, but can not play the application, the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cepRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.boot.domain.Cep
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
        at br.com.boot.application.Application.main(Application.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.boot.domain.Cep
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
        ... 21 common frames omitted

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cepRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.boot.domain.Cep
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
        at br.com.boot.application.Application.main(Application.java:20)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class br.com.boot.domain.Cep
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
        ... 21 more
```

My class Cep

```
@Entity
public class Cep {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String cep;

    public Cep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
        validarCep(cep);
    }
    protected Cep(){

    }
```

My Class CepRepository

```
public interface CepRepository extends CrudRepository<Cep, Long>{

    List<Cep> findbyId(Long id);
}
```

My Class CepController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cep")
public class CepController {

    @Autowired
    private CepRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/lista")
    public String retornaListaCeps(){
        Iterable<Cep> lista = repository.findAll();
        return lista.toString();
    }

}
```

My Class FactoryData

```
@Service
public class FabricaDados {

    @Autowired
    private CepRepository repository;

    public void gravarCeps() {
        repository.save(new Cep("14233-333"));
        repository.save(new Cep("14530-000"));
        repository.save(new Cep("14020-060"));
    }

    public Iterable<Cep> listarTodos() {
        Iterable<Cep> ceps = repository.findAll();
        return ceps;
    }
```

and my Class Main

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="br.com.boot")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="br.com.boot.repository")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        FabricaDados fabrica = ctx.getBean(FabricaDados.class);

        fabrica.gravarCeps();
        System.out.println(fabrica.listarTodos());

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Add an

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=br.com.boot.domain.Cep.class)
```

to your Application.class

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell Hibernate where to find your `@Entity` classes. Guessing in your case this should be

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=Cep.class)
...
public class Application {

    ...

}
```

Docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-the-default-package